# jquery related question

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am modifying the inner html through javascript, and the inner html involves a button
but when i put in the jquery code to run on the button click event it fails to do so ..
sorry but im a newb when it comes to javascript

content im adding into the html ..

```
function add()
{
    var val=document.getElementById("ans").value;

    document.getElementById("answers").innerHTML+="<tr><td>"+val+"<br/><p align=\"right\"><button class=\"replyb\">replies</button></p>"+"</td></tr>";

    document.getElementById("ans").value="";
}
```

jquery code ...

```
enter code here
```

Comment: ummm....where's the jquery code?

Comment: A more expressive title wouldn't hurt either. We know it is about `jquery` because it is tagged as such ;)

Comment: you can use firebug firefox add-on to debug the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following in your page at some place and it will handle clicks to all `.replyb` buttons whether you add them with javascript at any time, or not.

```
$(function(){

    $('button.replyb').live('click', function(){
      alert('clicked on button');
    });

});
```

have a look at [jquery `.live()` method](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Answer (score 1):

At a guess, because we don't have your jQuery, I would say you need to use [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) instead of `.click()` when you change the HTML the button will be **NEW** to the DOM.
When you apply your jQuery code, it adds any calls like `.click()` to any DOM item, when the page loads. So any **NEW** element doesn't have a `.click()` handler added to them.

Do solve this, you can change your `.click()`:

```
$('#someitem').click(function() {
    .....
});
```

To something like this:

```
$('#someitem').live('click', function() {
    .....
}
```